# How to stop cmd window from vanishing on VS19

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-2019

Been trying to stop the cmd window from vanishing right after I execute a program.
it vanishes without showing me the result.
The only method that worked for me was to type system("pause") but I realized its wrong.
what can I do?
b.t.w I'm coding CPP right now (was coding c before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop you program you can use getch() before the end of main func. Getch() reads one character after which the program moves on. I don’t know how correct this method is because I do not use windows myself, but it’s very common.